# (complex) Fourier series of $\text{abs}(x)$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Even if this problem was answered here before, I still think my solution process is different and needs some assistance.

Still the complex Fourier series is given by: $f(x) =\dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\displaystyle{\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}}c_n\,e^{-i\,n\,x}$

In my case $c_n$ is being calculation like: $c_n =\displaystyle{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|\,e^{-i\,n\,x}\,\mathrm{dx}=\int_{-\pi}^{0}-x\,e^{-i\,n\,x}\,\mathrm{dx}+\int_{0}^{\pi}x\,e^{-i\,n\,x}\,\mathrm{dx} }$

Solving this: $c_n = \left[\left(-\dfrac{t\,i}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)\,e^{-i\,n\,t}\right]_{-\pi}^{0}+\left[\left(\dfrac{t\,i}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)\,e^{-i\,n\,t}\right]_{0}^{\pi} = \dfrac{-2}{n^2}+2\,(-1)^n$

thus $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2\,\pi}\,\displaystyle{\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}}\left(\dfrac{-2}{n^2}+2\,(-1)^n\right)\,e^{-i\,n\,x}$. But I'm really not sure about that.

Comment: Just looking at it, there cannot be a $2(-1)^n$ term. Should that be divided by $n^2$?

Comment: You basically get an integral $\int_0^\pi xe^{inx}\mathrm dx$ which can be solved readily via integration by parts.

Comment: Actually I checked those 2 integrals by a program, but you‘re right it looks weird. Why solving for $\int_0^\pi x\,e^{i\,n\,x}$? I thought you can‘t sum it up like that since $e^{i\,n\,x}$ is neither odd nor even.

Comment: If the Fourier series is given by $e^{\color{red}{-} i n x}$ then the integral should be the inner product of $\text{abs}(x)$ against $e^{\color{orange}{+} i n x}$

Comment: What about $c_0$? your formula have a division by $0$

Comment: @jjagmath: Direct computation suggests it should be $\pi^2$.

Comment: @BrianTung I do know. The question was for the OP to realize that the case $n=0$ needs to be dealt with separately.

Comment: yea, of course, I had done that, but I just wanted to check the general idea first. Thank you for that hint though.

Comment: @mattos What you mean by that? I took it, the inner product of Fourier series is given by $ c_n = \langle f,e^{i\,n\,x}\rangle$ thus $c_n = \displaystyle{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|\,e^{-i\,n\,x}}$. I thought the complex conjugate is already taken into consideration.

Comment: @jjagmath: OK got it.

Comment: So is this the right one? Of course I'd add a $c_0$ in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
    \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|e^{-inx}dx & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|\cos(nx)dx \\
    &=2\int_0^\pi x\cos(nx)dx \\
    &=\left.2x\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\right|_{x=0}^{\pi}-2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}dx \\
    &=\left.2\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}\right|_{x=0}^{\pi}=2\left[\frac{(-1)^n-1}{n^2}\right]
\end{align}